# How to delete a line in bash (awk) with 2 conditions

Tags: bash, awk

i ve the following problem:
I have a file like:

```
1 3 4
2 5 6
3 1 3
4 1 0
5 7 0
6 0 1
```

and I would like to delete a line that contains in the second column 1 and in the third one the number 0. So the result should be:

```
1 3 4
2 5 6
3 1 3
5 7 0
6 0 1
```

I've tried with: `awk '$2!=1 && $3 != 0' file`

but it will delete also the lines: '5 7 0' and '3 1 3'

Any help?

Comment: Your problem is that you're phrasing your requirements in a negative way compared to how awk behaves and that's forcing you to think of your solution in a negative way and resulting in double negatives/complication. You don't want to "delete a line..." as that's not what awk does, awk SELECTS lines. So just phrase that in English to get "I want to select all lines where the 2nd field is not 1 or the 3rd field is not zero" and then simply translate to code as shown in most of the answers below as `awk ''$2!=1 || $3!=0' file`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will ensure that:

```
 awk '!($2==1 && $3==0){print}' file
```

i.e. print all lines except those with 2nd column is 1 and 3rd is 0.

Comment: The `{print}` is redundant.

Answer (score 6):

You want:

```
awk '!( $2==1 && $3 == 0)' file
```

or, equivalently:

```
awk '$2 != 1 || $3' file
```

Answer (score 3):

You're looking for the negation of `$2 == 1 && $3 == 0`. By the rules of logic, that's

```
awk '$2 != 1 || $3 != 0'
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
awk '$2$3!="10"' file
```

Cheers!

Comment: It's a common mistake to concatenate fields and test for matching some concatenated value but it would fail if, for example, $2 was "10" and $3 was "" so it's best avoided.